# Selenium testing with lists for load performance

Tags: java, scala, unit-testing, selenium, scalatest

I'm attempting to use a unit test of mine for "load" testing on our browser. For various reasons, we have seen performance degradation on the browser side, because we heavily rely on the print dialog.

I have the following unit test working via ScalaTest:

```
class LoadPrePaidSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with Chrome with Eventually {

implicit override val patienceConfig =
    PatienceConfig(timeout = scaled(Span(40, Seconds)), interval = scaled(Span(100, Millis)))
def build(csvLine:String):TestCSVHolder ={
    val split = csvLine.split(",")
    TestCSVHolder(memberId = split(0), preSaleCode = split(1),
      prePaidCode = split(2), lastName = split(3), firstName = split(4), badgeName = split(5))
  }

  def memberHelper(member: TestCSVHolder): Unit = {
    //insert member id via prepaid code
    textField("member_id").value = member.prePaidCode
    //fire keyup event
    executeScript("var eventToFire=jQuery.Event(\"keyup\");eventToFire.keyCode=221;eventToFire.which=221;" +
      "$(\"#member_id\").trigger(eventToFire)")
    eventually {
      val eles = webDriver.findElements(By.xpath(s"//*[contains(@id, '${member.memberId}')]"))
      eles.get(0).getTagName
      //We remove the head element because it just says Prep For Print
      val tdEles = (eles.get(0).findElements(By.tagName("td")).toList.tail)
      tdEles(0).getText() should be(member.lastName)
      tdEles(1).getText() should be(member.firstName)
      tdEles(2).getText() should be(member.badgeName)
    }
  }

  "Scanning an ID" should "look up the member" in {
    val member = new TestCSVHolder("100001", "ABCD", "[-100001-ABCD]", "John", "Doe", "JohnDoe")

    go to (url)
    //login
    textField("user_name").value = "mrkaiser"
    webDriver.findElementById("credentials").sendKeys("somepassword")
    click on ("btnLogin")
    //click to pre-paid
    click on linkText("Pre-Paid")
    memberHelper())
    webDriver.quit()
  }
}
```

However when I try to iterate through a list of elements using a foreach and passing in memberHelper, after a list of about 5 elements, I get the following stack trace:

```
The code passed to eventually never returned normally. Attempted 369 times over 40.110734904 seconds. Last failure message: Index: 0, Size: 0.
ScalaTestFailureLocation: LoadPrePaidSpec at (LoadPrePaidSpec.scala:43)
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedDueToTimeoutException: The code passed to eventually never returned normally. Attempted 369 times over 40.110734904 seconds. Last failure message: Index: 0, Size: 0.
    at org.scalatest.concurrent.Eventually$class.tryTryAgain$1(Eventually.scala:420)
    at org.scalatest.concurrent.Eventually$class.eventually(Eventually.scala:438)
    at LoadPrePaidSpec.eventually(LoadPrePaidSpec.scala:17)
    at LoadPrePaidSpec.memberHelper(LoadPrePaidSpec.scala:43)
    at LoadPrePaidSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LoadPrePaidSpec.scala:70)
    at LoadPrePaidSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LoadPrePaidSpec.scala:70)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:383)
    at LoadPrePaidSpec$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(LoadPrePaidSpec.scala:70)
    at LoadPrePaidSpec$$anonfun$1.apply(LoadPrePaidSpec.scala:54)
    at LoadPrePaidSpec$$anonfun$1.apply(LoadPrePaidSpec.scala:54)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Transformer.scala:22)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anon$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1647)
    at org.scalatest.Suite$class.withFixture(Suite.scala:1122)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.withFixture(FlatSpec.scala:1683)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.invokeWithFixture$1(FlatSpecLike.scala:1644)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1656)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1656)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:306)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.runTest(FlatSpecLike.scala:1656)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.runTest(FlatSpec.scala:1683)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1714)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1714)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:413)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:401)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:383)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:401)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:390)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:427)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:401)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:383)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:401)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:396)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsImpl(Engine.scala:483)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.runTests(FlatSpecLike.scala:1714)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.runTests(FlatSpec.scala:1683)
    at org.scalatest.Suite$class.run(Suite.scala:1424)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.org$scalatest$FlatSpecLike$$super$run(FlatSpec.scala:1683)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1760)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1760)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runImpl(Engine.scala:545)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.run(FlatSpecLike.scala:1760)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.run(FlatSpec.scala:1683)
    at org.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:55)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$3.apply(Runner.scala:2563)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$3.apply(Runner.scala:2557)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:383)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:2557)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1044)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1043)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:2722)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:1043)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:883)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2(ScalaTestRunner.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at LoadPrePaidSpec$$anonfun$memberHelper$1.apply$mcV$sp(LoadPrePaidSpec.scala:45)
    at LoadPrePaidSpec$$anonfun$memberHelper$1.apply(LoadPrePaidSpec.scala:43)
    at LoadPrePaidSpec$$anonfun$memberHelper$1.apply(LoadPrePaidSpec.scala:43)
    at org.scalatest.concurrent.Eventually$class.makeAValiantAttempt$1(Eventually.scala:394)
    at org.scalatest.concurrent.Eventually$class.tryTryAgain$1(Eventually.scala:408)
    ... 63 more
```

My end goal is to actually test something in the 20K range of elements from a file, but until I can get a small list like this working, I'm up a creek.

I'm using the chromedriver and am on Scala 2.11.6, scala test 2.2.0, selenium 2.35.0.

Comment: Looks like you made one call to 'eventually' with a lambda - try putting some logging in there to see what it's failing on for those 369 attempts.

Comment: Ah, I should clarify that I get no exceptions when a single run is issued. I get errors when I use a list and run through it many times. I'm attempting to do a stress test on the browserside.

Comment: What I am really attempting to do is try and see if there are memory leaks with the browser and how it handles printing. My team has seen IE fall under the load of the print dialog (we print something like 5 - 6K labels a day per machine) and since we are moving to Chrome we'd like to automate a test that will allow us to check if Chrome can handle the load.